# Getting rows from tables with same columns, but a different type

Tags: sql

Let's say I have the following tables

**Table A**

```
id    pk_id     name    value (Varchar)
 1      1       name     test name
 2      1       city     los angeles
```

**Table B**

```
id    pk_id    name    value (int)
 1      1       age      33
 2      1       amount   30
```

Is it possible to get the following results?

```
name     test name
age      33
```

when I do select tablea.*, tableb.* from tablea, tableb where tablea.pk_id=1 and tableb.pk_id=1, I get a one single row with all the columns.

Comment: This seems to be a very basic join query. But I would like to see some more rows on your example and how it would be the result from this rows. Can you add it?

Comment: @JorgeCampos add a new column and one row for each tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a `UNION` but with a particular thing since you have different types of fields and the `UNION` requires that all fields should be the same type.

So as you did not specify what your RDBMs is I will do it for oracle. But the basic idea is that you need just a function to convert your number column to a varchar column:

```
select name, value from tablea where pk_id=1 
UNION ALL
select name, TO_CHAR(value) from tableb where pk_id=1
```

It should give you what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

```
SELECT name, value FROM tablea WHERE id=<somevalue>
UNION ALL
SELECT name, CONVERT(varchar(10), value) FROM tableb WHERE pk_id=<somevalue>
```

You need to use the `UNION` keyword, but your columns must be the same data type

Answer (score -2):

You can use this..

```
         Select name,age
         from TableA,TableB
         where TableA.id=TableB.id;
```

Comment: No, he can't. age is not a column name in either table.